# CSS - Padding all around the dropdown list

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, primeng

Unable to have padding all around (top, bottom, left, right) a p-dropdown inside a p-table

Code...

```
<td>
    <p-dropdown name="country" [options]="countries" [(ngModel)]="applicant.country" placeholder="select country"
        (onChange)="getStatebyCountry(applicant.country,$event)" #country="ngModel" required>
    </p-dropdown>
</td>
```

Functionally its working fine, just its border is stick to column walls.

How to introduce padding all around a p-dropdown in p-table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a matter of adding a [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) css rule to style this element. Try adding code such as this to your stylesheet. I have added `!important`, since you may have other styles which could override this.

```
td {
  padding: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: answer upvoted - but a slight change in your answer, i had to give padding not inside p-dropdown rather inside <td> tag..

Comment: i have edited your answer what worked for me..hope you are fine plus i accepted it also

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
style="padding: 10px;"
```

inside p-dropdown tag.

Or do you have any styling code?

Comment: answer upvoted.. thanks had to give padding inside <td> tag rather p-dropdown tag